# how to disconnect the call in android 4.1.2 nexus programmatically

Tags: android, telephonymanager, nexus-s

i am able to disconnect the call programmatically for incoming unknown number call in android 2.2. But in android 4.1, its not working.

**Working Code to disconnect the call in android 2.2:**

```
private Class c;    
private  Method m;    
private com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService;    
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)     
{    
   Bundle b = intent.getExtras();    
   String state = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);    
   if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))   
   {    
     TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
     c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());    
     m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");    
     m.setAccessible(true);    
     telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);    
     telephonyService.silenceRinger();   
     telephonyService.endCall();    
   }    
}
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance

**Finally I got a solution for 2.6 version .**

`MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission is no longer working on silenceRinger() since 2.3+, but endCall is just fine. So the solution is to comment out the call to silenceRinger().

Comment: this is correct code.. can you post your logcat error.

Comment: TechEnd, there is no error in logcat. While(Unknown number) making the call, it should disconnect but this code working in android 2.2 but not in 4.1

Comment: Finally I got a solution for 2.6 version .MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission is no longer working on silenceRinger() since 2.3+, but endCall is just fine.

So the solution is to comment out the call to silenceRinger().

Comment: thnks techEnd....................

Answer (score 2):

MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is no longer working on silenceRinger() since 2.3+, but endCall is just fine.

So the solution is to comment out the call to silenceRinger().

And a simple example:

```
 http://androidbridge.blogspot.ro/2011/05/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-android.html
```

Cheers